# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError en NetBeans

Tags: java

Estaba usando NetBeans cuando por error he pulsado sobre un icono de de martillo con una escoba, equivalente a pulsar Mayus+F11 (clean and build project) es lo que me pone.

Al hacerlo cuando intento ejecutar el programa me sale el siguiente error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/manuelsagra/laxtore/utils/FileUtils
    at com.manuelsagra.laxtore.App.main(App.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.manuelsagra.laxtore.utils.FileUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Me dice que la clase no está, cuando sí que lo está. No sé ni qué hacer. El botón deshacer no me ha servido de nada, y no entiendo de dónde viene el error.

Comment: Lo que puede hacer es compilar nuevamente el proyecto o dar clic derecho sobre el y buscar opción que muestre compilar o compile.

Comment: La clase que no encuentra es `FileUtils`. ¿Verificaste que se encuentra efectivamente en esta ruta: `com/manuelsagra/laxtore/utils/FileUtils`? ¿Usaste Maven para agregar la clase o el proyecto corre con Maven? ¿Esa clase la agregaste tú directamente o la agrega otra librería que la utiliza?

Comment: @A.Cedano El fichero FileUtils.java está dentro de esa ruta. No sabría decirte cómo se agregó porque es un proyecto base de otro compa, yo lo he ido modificando a mi gusto.

Comment: Puedes hacer un primer intento: Hacer cualquier ligero cambio en el programa, por ejemplo un `System.out.println("ok");` y darle de nuevo a `Clean and Build`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me da un error: 
`Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 9
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`